# CSS body properties not inherited by h1 tag

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<body class="pageStyle">
<h1>The Amazing World of CSS</h1>
<p><strong>Sed ut perspiciatis</strong> unde omnis iste natus error sit <em>voluptatem accusantium</em> doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo <strong>inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae</strong> vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia  eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Learn more about CSS at the <a href="http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/">W3C CSS Home Page</a>.</p>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.pageStyle {
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/2tqxadpn/

Why is the `<h1>` tag not 18px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with CSS specificity. From [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> The following list of selector types is by increasing specificity:
>
> - Type selectors (e.g., h1) and pseudo-elements (e.g., :before).
> - Class selectors (e.g., .example), attributes selectors (e.g. [type="radio"]) and pseudo-classes (e.g., :hover).
> - ID selectors (e.g., `#example`).

Also note the `!important` exception:

> When an important rule is used on a style declaration, this declaration 
>   overrides any other declarations....

In your case, since the browser has default styles for all elements, and these styles are defined on the element's name (`h1`, `a`, etc...), they  have precedence over rules defined on parent elements or via CSS selectors,  so your styles are not applied. See this screenshot showing the browser's default styles for `h1`:

[image: UserAgent stylesheet for H1]

Try changing your styles to target `h2` or add the `pageStyle` class to `h2` to see.

Answer (score 2):

Because `h1` has some default styles, one of them is `font-size` which by default is `2em`, so you need to set `font-size` in `h1`

#### Snippet

```css
.pageStyle {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: inherit /* or 18px */
}
```

```html
<body class="pageStyle">
  <h1>The Amazing World of CSS</h1>
  <p><strong>Sed ut perspiciatis</strong> unde omnis iste natus error sit <em>voluptatem accusantium</em> doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo <strong>inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae</strong> vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
    Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Learn more about CSS at the <a href="http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/">W3C CSS Home Page</a>.</p>
</body>
```

**OP comment:**

> Ok, but isn't this style supposed to override it?

No it won't override because `body` is a parent. and the `h1` default styles is being applying directly to the `h1`, so regards to specificity it is more specific

**Further reading:**

[MDN CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

[Inheritance and cascade](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade)

[CSS Specificity](http://blog4coders.com/css-specificity)

Comment: Ok, but isn't this style supposed to override it?

Comment: Robert, right click and inspect element on your H1 element and you will see that it has default styles that have more weight than the parent styles

Comment: no it won't override because it is a parent. and the default is styling directly the `h1` so regards to specificity it is more specific

Comment: Thanks! Ok I see the inspect element thing and see that the browser crossed out the parent 18px value. I am studying upon inheritance and am testing the concepts out. If you have a link to more official documentation that covers what I posted it would greatly help.

Comment: I'd suggest `font-size: inherit;` rather than setting a specific size in multiple places (some of which will be inevitable over-looked when it comes to updating the CSS) *or* using `font-size: 1rem;` (the 'root-em' of the document) everywhere, but `inherit` is far easier. Or simply use a [css-reset stylesheet](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/) to set everything to a base-line default.

Comment: @RobertRocha i updated my answer with links to official docs (2 of them at least)

Comment: `font-size` for an `h1` _**might**_ be 36px, depending on your (the user) browser preferences. User-agent stylesheets generally specify sizes in ems and/or percents; for example inspecting this page in Chrome shows `font-size: 2em;` for the h1 _"CSS body properties not inherited by h1 tag"_

Comment: yup and 2em is 36px :) if the user keep the standard preferences. but I'll update it to 2em :)