# Failure to inherit

Tags: html, css

Hello Everyone I try to make all my page font-size 16px through inheritance but h1, h2 and h3 fail to inherit it, also please feel free to check my code for any other things i'm doing wrong and please suggest any change you find more appropriate. THANK FOR HELP.

Here's my snippet:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
}


/*************************HEADER*****************************************/

header {
  background-color: burlywood;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.header {
  margin: 0px;
}

#login {
  background-color: red;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

h3 {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#menuList {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.menuListItem {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}


/*************************SECTION****************************************/

section {
  background-color: crimson;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}


/*************************FOOTER*****************************************/

footer {
  background-color: indianred;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test-style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <!-------------------------------HEADER------------------------------------------------------>
  <header>
    <h1 class="header">Bienvenue</h1>
    <h2 class="header">Achat et Vente</h2>
    <form id="login" class="header" method="post" action="engine.php">
      <div id="emailContainer"><label for="email">E-mail</label><input type="email" name="email" id="email" /></div>
      <div id="passContainer"><label for="pss">Mot de passe</label><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /></div>
    </form>
    <h3 class="header"><span><a href="#">Connexion</a><span> ou  <span><a href="#">Créer un compte</a></span></h3>
    <nav class="header" id="MenuBar">
      <ul id="menuList">
        <li class="menuListItem">Acceuil</li>
        <li class="menuListItem">Categorie</li>
        <li class="menuListItem">Service</li>
        <li class="menuListItem">Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-------------------------------SECTION----------------------------------------------------->
  <section>
    <nav id="navInSection">
      <ul id="navList">
        <li>Acceuil</li>
        <li>Categorie</li>
        <li>Service</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="underSectionContainer" <form id="searchZone">
      <label for="search">Recherche</label><input type="search" name="search" id="search" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-------------------------------FOOTER------------------------------------------------------>
  <footer>
    <h4>Réseaux Sociaux</h4>
  </footer>

</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the `font-size` to every element within `<body>`. Use `body * {}` selector.

```css
body * {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
}


/*************************HEADER*****************************************/

header {
  background-color: burlywood;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.header {
  margin: 0px;
}

#login {
  background-color: red;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

h3 {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#menuList {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.menuListItem {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}


/*************************SECTION****************************************/

section {
  background-color: crimson;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}


/*************************FOOTER*****************************************/

footer {
  background-color: indianred;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test-style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <!-------------------------------HEADER------------------------------------------------------>
  <header>
    <h1 class="header">Bienvenue</h1>
    <h2 class="header">Achat et Vente</h2>
    <form id="login" class="header" method="post" action="engine.php">
      <div id="emailContainer"><label for="email">E-mail</label><input type="email" name="email" id="email" /></div>
      <div id="passContainer"><label for="pss">Mot de passe</label><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /></div>
    </form>
    <h3 class="header"><span><a href="#">Connexion</a><span> ou  <span><a href="#">Créer un compte</a></span></h3>
    <nav class="header" id="MenuBar">
      <ul id="menuList">
        <li class="menuListItem">Acceuil</li>
        <li class="menuListItem">Categorie</li>
        <li class="menuListItem">Service</li>
        <li class="menuListItem">Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-------------------------------SECTION----------------------------------------------------->
  <section>
    <nav id="navInSection">
      <ul id="navList">
        <li>Acceuil</li>
        <li>Categorie</li>
        <li>Service</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="underSectionContainer" <form id="searchZone">
      <label for="search">Recherche</label><input type="search" name="search" id="search" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-------------------------------FOOTER------------------------------------------------------>
  <footer>
    <h4>Réseaux Sociaux</h4>
  </footer>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Thank you Pugazh, But shouldn't the tags within the body tag inherit the font-size like they inherited the font-family ?

Comment: @AllenWalker - Here is the answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736718/css-body-properties-not-inherited-by-h1-tag

Comment: Does this selection h3.header means: select h3 inside header ?

Comment: No. It's - select the `h3` with `class="header"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot , you really helped me

Answer (score 0):

The heading elements do not inherit `font-size`, because they have this property set in a browser style sheet. This setting depends on the browser, but usually browsers use the [“expected” settings](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/rendering.html#sections-and-headings) described in HTML specifications. They include:

```
h1 { font-size: 2.00em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.50em; }
h3 { margin-top: 1.00em; }
```

If you want to make them inherit their parent’s `font-size`, you can set:

```
h1, h2, h3 { font-size: inherit; }
```

Instead of `inherit`, you can use the value `1em` or the value `100%` in this case, with identical results, except perhaps for some browser bugs.

Comment: Thank you Jukka K. Korpela !, Now I understand why it didn't work.